# What am I doing wrong here? cant get the correct matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

So I need to preallocate the matrix with NA and using a nested for loop create the matrix

```
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 0 0
3 2 1 1 1
4 2 1 1 1
5 2 2 1 1
```

but the closest I got was

```
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0
3 1 1 0 0
4 2 1 1 0
5 2 1 1 1
```

don't know if its a misprint in the question

here's my code

```
metrix <- matrix(NA_integer_,nrow = 5,ncol = 5)
for( i in 1:5)
{
  for(x in 1:5)
  {
    metrix[i, x] <- i %/% x
  } 
}
metrix
```

Comment: logic is not clear.  can you describe

Comment: The use of `%/%` indicates integer division, which correctly gives you the results you have. To create the desired matrix, you would need to be rounding perhaps, for example `metrix[i, x] <- round(i/x)`? My apologies if I am misunderstanding.